# What do I need to do before i switch / change a pointer variable pointed-to?

Tags: pointers

I do not want to mess up my RAM or make problem / bug that related to memory.
So.. what do I need to do before i switch / change a variable pointer pointed-to?

Or.. what i've doing is just fine?

Here is my source code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int x = 10;
    int y = 87;
    int arr[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};

    int *ptr;

    ptr = &x;
    printf("Now ptr pointed to x --> *ptr = %d  ~ ptr address: %p \n", *ptr, ptr);

    ptr = &y;
    printf("Now ptr pointed to y --> *ptr = %d  ~ ptr address: %p \n", *ptr, ptr);

    ptr = arr;
    printf("1st 2 byte: %d \n", *ptr);
    *ptr++;
    printf("2nd next 2 byte: %d \n", *ptr);
    *ptr++;
    printf("3rd next 2 byte: %d \n", *ptr);
    *ptr++;
    printf("4th next 2 byte: %d \n", *ptr);

    // Now i want to switch to x again :D
    ptr = &x;
    printf("Now ptr pointed to x AGAIN --> *ptr = %d  ~ ptr address: %p \n", *ptr, ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

Please enlightenment.

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be a problem with what you have. The pointer is simply changing where it points to, but those background variables are not being changed at all. The variables x, y and your array will be alive for as long as the main function is running, as they are within the scope of main. If you want them to be alive for even less time, you could restrict them to other functions that are called from main.

```
void xVariable()
{
     int x = 7;
}

int main()
{
    int y = 8;      

    xVariable();

    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        int z = 9;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

In this example, y will be alive the entire run of the program. x will only be alive while the function xVariable is running. i and z are only alive for the duration of the loop. This is all a basic example of how variable scope works, but I would recommend looking it further if memory is going to be important.

Comment: Your statement : `"The variables x, y and your array will be alive for as long as the main function is running, as they are within the scope of main"` is a new knowledge for me.. Thank you ^_^

Comment: No problem at all, glad to help. This is very important when trying to understand how variables can be accessed, so have a look at [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_scope_rules.htm) if you get time. It should be able to explain things much better than I.

Comment: any other reference for fundamental knowledge when we interacting with memory in C ?

Comment: I would get familiar with scope first, then move onto using pointers in different ways. After that, if you are feeling adventurous (and competent), you could take a look at things like malloc, alloc an realloc, which is all about dynamically assigning memory. You will also need to look into the function called free() if you are doing this. I would honestly recommend using C++ if you can, as it is backwards compatible with C, but has some really nice features that don't exist in C. Just make sure not to get too ahead of yourself, understanding the basics is critical to larger implementations.

Comment: My pleasure! Good luck with your research!